# The easiest way to find the active element text type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following structure in the project (each gameobject looks like this), in which (the simplest) way I can get to the element "text" but only the one that will be active. And only one will be active for the entire duration of the game

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is always only exactly one object of a certain type active in your Scene you can use [`FindObjectOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html) like

```
var activeText = FindObjectOfType<Text>();
```

If there is no active GameObject with an enabled component `Text` this returns `null`.

---

For looking under a specific GameObject use

```
// however you get this object reference
GameObject theObject;
var activeText = GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
```

[`GetComponentInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentInChildren.html) by default also only returns the first encountered active and enabled component of given type or `null` if none was found.